# Numerical integration by quadrature rule

Tags: integration

i am integrating the following using quadrature rule in matlab. 
my functions are
    S(1)=0.25(1-s)*(1+t), S(2)=0.25(1+s)*(1+t),S(3)=0.25(1-s)*(1+t)
     I try to integrate such

```
         for i=1:3
          g(i)=(quad rule)
          end
```

s,t=-1 to 1. this will give me 1-by-3 row vector.
I do not know how to integrate by quadrature rule. anyone can give some direction.

Comment: Be more specific. Do you want a  2D quadrature? Do you know any such rules?

Comment: yes 2D. As we have in that rule, if 'a' and 'b' are the limits of integral then  for a weight function w(i), we can write  sum(w(i)*f(x(i))). we can also apply mid point rule which is easy to apply.